# Sorting integers using comparison-based sorting in linear time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Have an array A = [a1, a2, ..., an] where each element in the array is either 0, 1 or 2.

Need to sort the array, but it is stated specifically use a **comparison-based algorithm**. I know it is possible to use linear time algorithms, but you are not allowed to use counting sort or other arrays.

Can anyone help me to where to start from. I'm assuming we know that 1 is the median, but what technique would you use to sort this in place?

Comment: Somewhere there is a proof that comparison sorting can't be done in linear time. What makes you think it's possible?

Comment: @MarkRansom I assume the fact that there are only 3 values means you can sort them by iterating over the array twice, which would make it linear (if you consider the number of values to be a constant).

Comment: @m69 I appear to have glossed over that part, thanks.

Comment: This sounds like the [Dutch National Flag problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) and there is a simple linear solution.

Comment: @m69 There is no restrictions on what you compare with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort an array with only 3 values by only comparing elements with each other (even without knowing the type of the elements or the three values, when given a compare function), e.g. like this:

Compare the first two elements; if one is greater than the other, then the smaller one is either 0 or 1, and the greater one is either 1 or 2. Put the smaller one in front, and swap the greater one with the last element. Then compare the second (swapped) and third element, put the smaller one in second place and swap the greater one with the last-but-one element, and so on. If two elements are equal, compare them to a third element, and so on, until you find a difference, and move several elements to the end if necessary.

The result of this is an array where the first zone is all 0 or 1, and the second zone is all 1 or 2. Each of these zones can then be sorted in a similar way, resulting in a completely sorted array after iterating over the array twice.

Example:

```
state:   2,1,2,1,0  
compare: ^ ^  
swap:    1,2,2,1,0  
move:      ^     ^  
state:   1,0,2,1,2  
compare:   ^ ^  
swap:    1,0,2,1,2  
move:        ^ ^  
state:   1,0,1,2,2
```

Because there are an odd number of elements, we have to check whether the middle element belongs to the first or second zone, by comparing it to the previous element (and if they are the same also to the next element). In the example, the middle element is 1, so it doesn't really make a difference.

Now we have two zones:

```
zone1:   1,0  
zone2:   1,2,2
```

Each of these can then be sorted seperately:

```
state:   1,0  
compare: ^ ^  
swap:    0,1

state:   1,2,2  
compare: ^ ^  
swap:    1,2,2
move:      ^ ^  
state:   1,2,2
```

In this phase, we don't have to check the middle element in an odd-length zone.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood (or made a mistake) this doesn't seem to work for [2, 1, 2, 1, 0] After the first iteration I believe you get 10122 and the second time you get 01212. Does it need to be 3 iterations?

Comment: @phil I'll add a run-through of an example to the answer.

Comment: Oh does the 'pointer' to the last - k element stay on the second iteration or does it reset to the last element again?

Comment: @phil in the second phase, the two zones are treated seperately.

Comment: Thank you for this solution! This also helped me visualize a little better: https://coderbyte.com/algorithm/dutch-national-flag-sorting-problem

Comment: @phil Yes, the standard solution involves identifying the elements, as in `if (arr[mid] === 0)`, but I wanted to find a method that was literally "comparison-based", and only compared elements with other elements.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Take 1 as the pivot element. Compare with every element. If that is `0`, move it before `1` and if it is `2`, then move it after `1`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

void Sort(vector<int>& A) {
    int n = A.size(), i = 0, j = 0, k = n - 1;
    while (j < k) {
        if (A[j] == 0) swap(A[i++], A[j++]);
        else if (A[j] == 2) swap(A[k--], A[j]);
        else ++j;
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> A {2, 1, 2, 1, 0};
    Sort(A);
    copy(A.begin(), A.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript solution. Algorithm is run twice with pivot=1 and pivot=0 based on partition. You can see the algorithm performs COMPARISION rather than knowing 0, 1 or 2.

```
var array = [1,0,2,0,0,1,2,0,2,1,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,1];
console.log("Original Array " + array);
var size = array.length;

function partition(array, s, e, pivot) {

    var i = s - 1;
    var j = s;
    while (j < e) {
        if (array[j] <= pivot) {
            var swap = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = array[j];
            array[j] = swap;
            i++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    return i;
}

var parti = partition(array, 0, size, 1)
console.log("After one pass " + array);
console.log("Partition " + parti);
partition(array, 0, parti + 1, 0);
console.log("Final    Array " + array);
```